# when i use the appvirality webhook getting this error {"success":false,"message":"Unknown Error Occured."}

Tags: php

I have new in php webhook. i want to get the data from the appvirality dashboard using the php webhook. but i can't able to get the data from the AppVirality deshboard.i am getting this response

> {"success":false,"message":"Unknown Error Occured."}

below is my request code

```
function genral_curl_call($curl_url,$curl_data,$method) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('ContentType:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
    return $result;
}

$curl_data = array(
    "apikey" => "api key",
    "privatekey" => "private key",
    "pagenum" => "50",
    "fromdate" => null,
    "todate" => "11-Aug-2016 7:10",
    "status" => "All"
);

$method = "POST";
$curl_url = "https://api.appvirality.com/v1/getreferrerrewards";
$curl_result = genral_curl_call($curl_url,$curl_data,$method);

echo $curl_result;
```

Comment: `$data` should be `$curl_data`

Comment: also try to use `http_build_query($curl_data)` because its recommended if you are using PHP5 upwords.

Comment: yes i try it . but  not result is same....